# Простые функции в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в конце этих двух функций ставится 
`return true`?

```
function changeImage(){
    document.getElementById("littlebrain").style.height ="35%";
    document.getElementById("littlebrain").style.width ="35%";
    return true;
};

function alertMe(){
    alertmsg = document.littlebrain.src + '\nHeight: ' + document.littlebrain.height + '\nWidth: ' + document.littlebrain.width;
    alert(alertmsg);
    return true;
}
```

Расскажите или подскажите в какую сторону искать ответ.

Comment: Потому. А если серьезно, то без контекста использования функций нельзя назвать конкретную причину использования `return true`

Comment: Контекст использования - банально изменение DOM а точнее размера картинки.
Первая функция от размера экрана зависит размер изображения.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример кода, использующего эти функции.

Answer (score 1):

Эти функции, строго говоря, являются процедурами. Действие, выполняемое в каждой из них, имеет побочные эффекты. Следовательно, значение, возвращаемое ими, не должно играть роли, иначе это плохой стиль программирования. Единственный нормальный кейс - они используются как обработчики DOM-событий, либо как часть иного цикла обработчиков, в котором важно возвращаемое значение, предположим, для "всплытия" событий, т.е. это флажок-настройка поведения обработчика.

**Обновление**

Javascript - функциональный язык, с функциями - объектами первого порядка, и хотя он позволяет писать в любом стиле, разумно использовать функциональный подход, а именно - стремиться к тому, чтобы функции были чистыми, т.е их результат зависел только от входных данных и чтобы они не производили побочных эффектов. Это облегчает отладку и тестирование, а потому является общепринятой практикой в сообществе Javascript.

Comment: "Действие, выполняемое в каждой из них, имеет побочные эффекты. Следовательно, значение, возвращаемое ими, не должно играть роли, иначе это плохой стиль программирования." -- это почему?